# How to make button disable with error message from response and after one click using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a send Button, that contains 2 Api in it.
So, if the input box is empty then send the button is disabled.
Now i want 2 conditions to work,
1. if i get an error message from the response saying

```
Email-Id you provided is not exist in medicamind account,
```

then my send button must be disabled untill Correct email is given.

2. After giving Email-Id and click on save button, it must get disabled after one click.
   If i edit again on input box then it must be enabled or it must be in disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr disabled of the button :. If you get an error put it to true and when the correct one is received put it to false.
For the second case just put (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail); booleanVar = false" must be enought. I hope it could help you!

Comment: Thanks for response, Can you please give me an example

Comment: <button [disabled]="booleanVar" (click)="generateEmailOtp(enterSms,enterEmail); booleanVar = false" class="btn pull-right otp" *ngIf="isConfirmEmailOtp || isSms">Send OTP</button>
Put 'booleanVar' = true in yout ts, then in your service response put this.booleanVar = true (error) and this.booleanVar = false (success)

Comment: And if you put a <button [attr.disabled]="booleanVar" > ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple events, I think you know it. So you need to validate two things:

1- Validate Email;
2- OnClick you call your method which returns something but once it's clicked you need to disable it again.

You can validate email as the user's type, since you are using template driven form you use keyup event to validate your email using regex. Like this:

```
<!-- HTML File -->
<input 
   type="text" 
   [(ngModel)]="inputData" 
   (keyup)="keyUpMethod()" >

<button 
   [disabled]="checkBtn"
   (click)="apiCallMethod()">

// .ts File
inputData: string;         // input Data
checkBtn: boolean = false; // Declare it initially as false

// This method fires when the user types
keyUpMethod() {
   if (this.validateEmail(this.inputData)) {
      this.inputData = true; // this enables your button
   } else {
      // if you want to add any exception, it goes here
   }
}

// for validation of email
validateEmail(email) {
   // validate your email here
   return either true or false;
}

// this is will trigger when the user clicks on the button
apiCallMethod() {
   this.inputData = false;  // Disable the button again
   // your button is disabled and you are already in this method, now you can do the 
   // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, what you gave is correct i guess, but i am not getting how to do that.. say according to my requirement please

Comment: It would take me few hours to get back to you, as I am involved with some urgent work now at office. Atleast try to understand and give it a try.

and if you are still not able to do it then I will answer you again later today...

Comment: Thanks that you had made time and replied